# RINS: start - incumbent and relaxation solution have all different values

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

RINS: Relaxation induced neighborhood search; introduced by Danna et.al in 2010 [this paper](http://%20download.springer.com/static/pdf/696/%E2%80%A6*~hmac=7b18027492f15466ea8d93356d3c7d034b635e%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B29959bee1871bb302bef8d96ab).

I wanted to design an example how the RINS algorithm works to make sure that I have it completly understood completly.

As it turns out, I do not know what happens if I am currently at a node where RINS should be applied and there are no values in the incumbent and the relaxation solution that equal to each other? How do I decide on which node to branch then?

Or can someone forward me to a very insightful example? I mean the overall procedure is clear, I am just not sure about the details. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a pertinent reference to RINS (I never heard of this group of 4 capital letters before...) ?

Comment: Sorry, sure, I added it